# How do I define a Regex that will match blockquotes in Markdown?

Tags: regex

I want to write a Regex that will match Markdown blockquotes. Basically lines starting with `>`, and after the first one they're not needed. The blockquote ends by having a double newline then text.

Right now this is what my Regex looks like:

```
(^> ?[^\n]+\n*)+
```

[image]

Which as you can see in the screenshot, matches pretty well, but the line before the `reist` line, the line before the non-quoted text, shouldn't be highlighted in yellow, it shouldn't be part of the blockquote and thus shouldn't be identified by the Regex.

How can I prevent this? Negative lookarounds?

Comment: Not clear. Wouldn't `/(^>.*?\n{2})/s` work better for you? [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK5dC6/1)

Comment: @anubhava No, because per that demo the two at the top are two, when they should just be one blockquote, as there's not two lines then a non-blockquote line to separate them. That's one valid blockquote. I want to be able to detect the one blockquote of this format without having it include the delimiting newline.

Comment: Is this specifically for objective-c regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have the linebreaks (\n*) inside your capture group. So try this one:

```
(^> ?.+?)((\r?\n\r?\n\w)|\Z)
```

(^> ?.+?) => capture everything which starts with > and stop capturing when ...
((\r?\n\r?\n\w)|\Z)  => ... the first double linebreak with following char is found or if the string ends (\Z)

Check out the demo: https://regex101.com/r/eK5dC6/3

Comment: This is close, but the top two matches should be one match, as there wasn't a double newline followed by a non-blockquote line.

Comment: @DougSmith I edited my answer. Please check. What should happen if there are 3 or more linebreaks? Would this also terminate the blockquote?

Comment: It captures the first character of the non-blockquote string?

Comment: "It captures the first character[...]" - That doesn't matter because this capture is in another capture group. Take the value of the first capture group and you'll get your blockquote. What about my other question (three linebreak terminator)? See this example: https://regex101.com/r/eK5dC6/4